# How to query the item quantity of a Box folder using the API

Tags: box-api

We are using Box API v2.0.

Based on the documentation, the following command should return the list of items of the root folder along with the item_collection field for every folders.

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?fields=item_collection -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Unfortunately, the **item_collection** field is ignored and the mini format is returned.

From the documentation:

> Any attribute in the full files or folders objects can be passed in
>   with the fields parameter to get specific attributes, and only those
>   specific attributes back; otherwise, the mini format is returned for
>   each item by default.

Do you know if this is a known issue and if there is any workaround?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the number of items in the immediate (root) folder, or the total number of items in the user's Box?

Comment: Seems like we should probably say "Most attributes" instead of "Any attribute."   There are clearly some exceptions where ?fields doesn't make as much sense to us, so we don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually an error in the documentation. `item_collection` is currently not supported for the /folders/{id}/items endpoint (Documentation is being updated).

Comment: It looks like this has been lost between the first and second API version. Is there an alternate way to display the item quantity of all listed folders without performing an API call for every folder to get the _item_collection_ field?